# fix multi-line CSV string without quotes (using PHP)

Tags: php, csv, file-io

I have a CSV file where strings with a comma get quotes around it, but strings without a comma in it do not get quotes around it.
The issue: multi-line strings (without a comma) do not get quotes around them. How do I treat them as one field?

E.g. lines 3-5 have no quotes around the multi-line strings:

```
id1,h2,h3,h4
2,2a:with comma and quote / middle field,"3,a
b
c",4a
3,2a:no comma no quote / last field,3a,4a
b
c
4,2a:no comma no quote / middle field,3a
b
c,4a
5,2a:no comma no quote / middle and last field,3a
b
c,4a
b
c
```

**Q: what is the preferred / cleanest way to create the wanted output, preferably using PHP (or awk / sed / Python / Perl / other *nix CLI tools)?**

- option a (preferred): put quotes around the multi-line strings
- option b (workaround): use a separator (e.g. | ) instead of newline for the multi-line strings that don't have quotes

**option A: preferred - put quotes around the multi-line strings**

```
id1,h2,h3,h4
2,2a:with comma and quote / middle field,"3,a
b
c",4a
3,2a:no comma no quote / last field,3a,"4a
b
c"
4,2a:no comma no quote / middle field,"3a
b
c",4a
5,2a:no comma no quote / middle and last field,"3a
b
c","4a
b
c"
```

**option B: workaround - use a separator (e.g. | ) instead of newline for the multi-line strings that don't have quotes**

```
id1,h2,h3,h4
2,2a:with comma and quote / middle field,"3,a
b
c",4a
3,2a:no comma no quote / last field,3a,4a|b|c
4,2a:no comma no quote / middle field,3a|b|c,4a
5,2a:no comma no quote / middle and last field,3a|b|c,4a|b|c
```

In my text file:

- every row always has 4 fields (either on one line, or split over multiple lines when it contains a multi-line string)
- there are quotes around the string if there is a comma in the string
  (also applies to multi-line strings)
- the first column is an integer
- only string fields should get quotes around it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using at the moment. It works (for me), but I have the feeling it can be done in a (much) more efficient way.

```
<?php

$inputFile = "test.csv"; 
$outputFile = "output.csv";

$in = fopen($inputFile, "r") or die("could not open ".$inputFile);
$out = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

$rowCount = 0;

//column count
$firstLine = fgetcsv($in);
$columnCount = count($firstLine);
fputcsv($out, $firstLine);

$buffer = array();

while ($line = fgetcsv($in) ) {

    $rowCount++;

    // new line: put in buffer
    if (!count($buffer)) {
        $buffer = $line; 
        continue;
    }

    // new line is not starting with number, and not complete
    if (count($line) != $columnCount && !is_numeric($line[0]) ) {
        $first = array_shift($line);
        $buffer[count($buffer)-1] .= "\n". $first;
        $buffer = array_merge($buffer,$line);
    }

    // row is complete
    if (count($line) == $columnCount || (count($line)>0 && is_numeric($line[0]) ) && count($buffer) == $columnCount ) {
        fputcsv($out, $buffer);
        $buffer = $line;
    }
}

// write final buffer
if (count($buffer)) {
    fputcsv($out, $buffer);
}

fclose($in);
fclose($out);

?>
```